# Can not unpin the object until it is saved on parse server using Android-Parse-SDK

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I can not unpin my object from local database until it is saved on backend.
I save object to local database then call `object.saveEventually()` like this

```
object.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if(e == null) {

                                object.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if(e == null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(AppContext.get(), "Object Saved On Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(AppContext.get(), "Object Not Saved On Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

if i want to unpin this object before internet connection back and object is saved on back-end what should i do.
I tried this but it's not working:

```
object.unpinInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if(e == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.object_deleted),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    updateObjectsList();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.object_not_deleted),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

How i can cancel `object.saveEventually()`?

Comment: I have a similar issue with objects that I only store locally. The local objects contain pointers to objects that are stored online, do not know if that is part of the problem. My problem is similar, cannot unpin the objects. No errors or anything, so seems unpinned, but it is not. Hope a savvy Parse guy can explain what causes the behavior.

Comment: Using Bolts (comes together with the API - saveEventually() with no arguments returns a Bolt task), you should be able to cancel: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#cancelling-tasks